# Login different to Login Name

Tags: sql-server-2005, authentication, user-management

I am currently working with SQL Server 2005 and I had the question arising whether you can have a Login with a different Loginname. I came to ask the question as the query

```
SELECT * FROM master.sys.syslogins
```

throws up, amongst others, the two columns "name" and "loginname" both displaying the same values.
So I asked myself if it was possible to have a Login called "XTest" where the user can actually log on with the Username "Test"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible! Both columns have always the save value. You should not use `sys.syslogins` (in any database) at all in any current SQL Server version. This table is still provided for backward compatibility, use `sys.server_principals` and `sys.sql_logins` instead.